# Order of creation of static objects

Tags: c++

I had some code such as this:

**main.cpp**

```
/* create a global object to help manage malloc */
struct MemoryHelper {
    void * (*malloc_fn)( size_t );
    bool initialized;
} MemHelper = { malloc, true };

int main() { /* some stuff */ }
```

I was surprised that during `dynamic initialization` the value of `MemHelper.initialized` was `true`, but the value of `MemHelper.malloc_fn` was `NULL`.

This appeared to show that the object was created with a mixture of both `static` and `dynamic` initialization.

Is this a compliant pattern - are objects guaranteed to be fully initialized, or not initialized?

Is there a way of guaranteeing the full initialization?

Comment: It's not either/or. It's first static, then dynamic if necessary.

Comment: Unless the object isn't fully initialised at the beginning of `main`, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Seems like constant initialization was preformed on only part of the object. It's allowed by the *as-if* rule, I think. The solution to your problem is to not have an `initialized` flag to indicate the function can be used, check the pointer isn't a nullptr. Zero initialization is **guaranteed**.